# hl-line-mode -- how to highlight only the text on the current line (don't highlight leading and trailing whitespace)?

Tags: doom, highlighting, hl-line-mode

I'd like to highlight only the text in between the leading and trailing whitespace on each line. For example, I'd only like to highlight the region marked by the double arrow `<-->` for the following line:

```
    public static void printSum() {...}
    <--------------------------------->
```

I run Doom Emacs and understand that `hl-line-mode` is responsible for highlighting the current line. It appears that if I defined my own `hl-line-range-function` to do what I wanted, I could apply this to any major mode (I want it on the dashboard).

It seems that `hl-line-range-function` needs to return a cons cell of the starting and ending "positions" of where I'd like to highlight. What is the "position" data type? How is it represented? Can I simply return the value of functions like `end-of-visual-line` and `back-to-indentation`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: A guess, without looking, is that "position" is just a buffer position. If so, the after moving with either of those functions you need to return `(point)`. And you can wrap the movement and call to `point` in a `save-excursion`. On the other hand, maybe there's a function that gives you the position directly. At least the doc of those functions doesn't claim that they do, so even if they might you shouldn't count on that.

Comment: It would be easier to do this by setting the `:extend` attribute of the `hl-line` face to nil. When it's set to `nil`, the hl-line highlight will only affect positions of the line where characters are located (including whitespace).  If you want it to only be effective in the dashboard, you can create a new face and use `setq-local` in `dashboard-mode`'s hook to set that face as the value of `hl-line-face` only in the dashboard buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As Drew suggested, this works:

```
(defun my-hl-line-range-function ()
  (let ((beg (save-excursion
           (back-to-indentation)
           (point)))
        (end (save-excursion
           (end-of-visual-line)
           (point))))
    (cons beg end)))

(setq hl-line-range-function #'my-hl-line-range-function)
```